# How to create a translucent(the space below the window should be Clickable) window for java SE 1.5?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, transparency, java-5

I have come across many articles that makes transparent window(i.e by taking a screencapture and drawing that image as background). But using them i can't do anything over the space that is occupied by my applet(as it's not click-through).

I also want to know when would the transparent area be clickable?

Can anyone help me with some references?

Answer (score 1):

Below are some good examples to do so:

http://www.andrels.com/wp-en_US/index.php/2010/03/creating-transparent-and-shaped-windows-using-java-swingawt/

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/

http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/03/18/translucent-and-shaped-swing-windows.html

Comment: Note that they all use `com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities` which is not part of the official Java API. It is discouraged to use it in a productive system!

Comment: thanx for the links. They require AWTUtilities which is a part of java SE 6 update 10. But i want to do it for java SE 5. If You come across designing in java 5, please let me know